# Can I use index to get a set element in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, set

Suppose I have a set in Ruby s1:

```
#<Set: {12, 25}>
```

I use s1.find_index(12) to get the index 0
Can I use the index to get back the set element, something like s1[0] to get back 12?

The reason I want to do this is my set elements are large.  I want to store links between the set elements.  I use the index to store the links.

I am using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Why bother with indexes when your "large elements" are just references anyway? Why not simply store the pointer/reference?

Comment: What you are trying to do defeats the purpose of sets. You don't seem to understand what a set is.

Comment: @muistooshort what I am doing is creating these data structures and then writing them to JSON.  I think what I should do is save the large values in the links and before writing to JSON convert to index to save space in the JSON.

Comment: In that case, you should be using an Array instead of a Set.

Comment: @muistooshort I want unique elements - that's why I used the set

Comment: But sets aren't ordered, hence nort's suggestion to use an array for the indexes and a hash to help maintain uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an `Array` and a `Hash` for this.

```
ary = []
hsh = {}

unless hsh[item]
  hash[item] = ary.size
  ary << item
end
```

Then when you look up the item in `hsh` later you will have the index of the item in the list and effectively you will have the internals of your set with a specific caveat

Answer (score 0):

That might not be possible. [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is an unordered list.

> Set implements a collection of **unordered** values with no duplicates. This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and Hash's fast lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element from a set by its index in this way:

```
my_set = Set.new([1, 4, 7])
if index = my_set.find_index(4)
  puts my_set.to_a[index]
end
```